# Lookup using multi criteria

Tags: google-sheets

If anyone can help with this:

- sheeet2 has the data
- sheet4 is how I want to see the data.

Need to search by column A and row 1 to get the value in sheet2 column E

[Sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gGY-tmxMXmHBohK1z93_6WcMsciWhU5AIcJljWCt-gA/edit#gid=1608059618)

Comment: access denied. share your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
=QUERY(sheeet2!A1:C; "select A, B, C where A ='"&sheeet2!A1&"'"; 0)
```